# How can I include javascript and css in a flexdashboard?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have created a flexdashboard that includes a map using the leaflet package.

I need to be able to select markers within a region of the map so that I can display summary statistics based upon those markers. [leaflet-locationfilter](https://github.com/kajic/leaflet-locationfilter) appears to provide what I need, but I need to figure out how to include this in the generated HTML file. I have tried using "includes" in the flexdashboard header but this produces an error. Here is a simple test case:

```
---
title: "Dashboard Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    includes: includes(in_header = "TEST.HTML", before_body = "TEST.HTML", after_body = "TEST.HTML")
---
```

...where TEST.HTML is:

```
<!-- TEST TEST TEST -->
```

But this fails with:

> output file: Dashboard.knit.md
>
> Error in includes$in_header : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>   Calls:  ->  -> overlay -> pandoc_include_args
>   Execution halted

I have had to resort to reading [the code](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/blob/master/R/flex_dashboard.R) to figure out how to do this because it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, but I've obviously missed something.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using R's built-in `includes` function like the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexdashboard/flexdashboard.pdf) (pg. 4) oddly says to do, use YAML instead:

```
---
title: "Dashboard Title"
    output: 
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
        includes: 
            in_header: "TEST.HTML"
            before_body: "TEST.HTML"
            after_body: "TEST.HTML"
---
```

However, there is a different way of including leaflet plug-ins besides through flexdashboard. Use leaflet's own `dependencies` argument:

```
map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(htmlDependency(
    name = "Leaflet.locationfilter",
    version = "0.1",
    src = "PATH_TO_DIRECTORY",
    script = "locationfilter.js",
    stylesheet = "locationfilter.css"
)))
```